# Error message when trying to resize with cv2.resize

Tags: python, opencv, image-resizing

I'm trying to load a `.npy` file and resize it with `cv2.resize` but I get the following error message:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1-dev) /home/name/opencv_build/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3688: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !dsize.empty() in function 'resize'

This is my code:

```
filepath = 'data.npy'
img = np.load(filepath)
print(img.shape)
res = cv2.resize(img, (352, 1216))
```

Output of `print(img.shape)` is `(1, 1, 192, 640)`.

Comment: dim is the dimension of the .npy files which are generated when I set the flag --pred_metric_depth using the monodpth2 framwork: https://github.com/nianticlabs/monodepth2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

images in opencv should only have 2 dim if grayscale/single channel or 3 dim if color. you seem to have a gray/single channel image [192,640] thats wrapped in 2 lists [1,1,---]

so to get the image you need to get it from inside those 2 lists.

`img = np.load(filepath)[0][0]`

or if you are not sure how many lists its wrapped in, you can do

`img = np.squeeze(np.load(filepath)`

but that will work as long as there is only 1 image in those lists

Comment: @thank you that helped a lot. I used resphaped before I used cv2.resize() and now everything is working fine! have a nice day!